# Apache PDFBox - Not able to read all web links from PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to extract all hyperlinks from PDF file. I am using **Apache PDFBox version 2.0.11**. I am using below code snippet, but in some PDF files I am getting page annotation size as **"0"**. But on that particular page hyperlinks are available. Please find the problematic PDF file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GpbPsZr_OvunLBRr2iD5ElkNeKFPaRfy . Page number 2 contain hyperlink. So please check it and help me to extract these hyperlinks.

```
    PDDocument doc = null;
    doc = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Users\\A883\\Desktop\\AEM.01938-18.pdf"));
    for (int i = 0; i < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++i)
    {
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(i);
        List<?> annots = page.getAnnotations();
        System.out.println("Size of annotations "+annots.size());
        for(Object o:annots){
            if(o instanceof PDAnnotationLink){
                System.out.println("Page "+(i+1)+" contains link.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no hyperlink there, i.e. no annotation. This may be some magic by Adobe Reader.